# Base Stage in azure build pipeline is it possible or how it works?

Tags: azure-devops

New to Azure Devops

I am building a xamarin mobile build pipeline that contains 4 Stages - Dev-QA,Staging,Production

For all the stages I have to repeat the same steps and this increases build time.
The reason for these stages its variable eg "Dev" "Prod" etc..

EG

- Nuget installer
- Nuget restore
- Build Solution
- etc

Can I have a stage called "base" and does all the base tasks 
and the other stages just do their remaining tasks.

For some reasons when I tried it did not work.

any clarification .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should create a Task Group for the reusable tasks that belong in all the stages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts